# Rabbitmq no Node.js com ampqlib não fazendo broadcast das mensagens

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Esse script deveria ser um tipo de chat em linha de comando somente para o estudo do rabbitmq.

Seriam abertos execuções do programa em paralelo. Cada execução cria um consumer da mesma fila e todo texto enviado por uma execução do programa deveria ser enviado para todas consummers através de um exchange do tipo **fanout**.

Acontece que embora eu tenha configurado o exchange como fanout ele não está fazendo broadcast das mensagens. Ele está se comportando como um load balancer enviando a mensagem para cada consumer por vez.

```
const amqplib = require('amqplib');
const readline = require("readline");

class Chat {

    async init() {
        await this.configureChannel();
        await this.configureConsumer();
        await this.configureCommandLine();
    }

    async configureChannel() {
        const conn = await amqplib.connect('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672');
        const ch = await conn.createChannel();
        await ch.assertExchange("chat", "fanout", {});
        const { queue } = ch.assertQueue('messages');
        await ch.bindQueue(queue, 'chat', '');
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    async configureConsumer() {
        await this.ch.consume("messages", logMessage);
        function logMessage(msg) {
            if (msg.content)
                console.log("\n[*] Recieved message: '%s'", msg.content.toString())
        }
    }

    async configureCommandLine() {
        const commandLine = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });
        this.commandLine = commandLine;
    }

    async run() {
        const prompt = () => {
            this.commandLine.question("Message: ", async (mensagem) => {
                debugger;
                if (mensagem === "sair") {
                    return this.commandLine.close();
                }
                await this.ch.publish("chat", 'messages', Buffer.from(mensagem), {});
                prompt();
            });
        }
        await this.init();
        console.log("\nChat\n");
        prompt();
    }

}

const chat = new Chat();
chat.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado na resposta dada no StackOverflow em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324760/rabbitmq-innode-js-with-amqplib-not-broadcasting-fanout-messages/68329407#68329407

Supondo que você execute várias instâncias desse script como está, o problema aqui é que você está usando uma fila para todos os consumidores. Um exchange do tipo fanout envia cada mensagem recebida para todas as filas que estão vinculadas ao exchange. Mas cada fila (se tiver vários consumidores) funcionará no estilo de rodízio (round-robin) - supondo que haja algum limite na contagem do prefetch. Para obter o comportamento fanout, você precisa executar cada instância do script com uma fila diferente.

As solução estaria na alterações destas linhas:

```
...
async configureChannel() {
    const conn = await amqplib.connect('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672');
    const ch = await conn.createChannel();
    await ch.assertExchange("chat", "fanout", {});
    this.ch = ch;
}

async configureConsumer() {
    const { ch } = this;
    const { queue } = await ch.assertQueue('', { exclusive: true });
    await ch.bindQueue(queue, 'chat', '');
    ch.consume(queue, logMessage);
    function logMessage(msg) {
        if (msg.content)
            console.log("\n[*] Recieved message: '%s'", msg.content.toString())
    }
}
...
```